# What do I need to compile a program against a much older Linux kernel on a different architecture?

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, cross-compiling, dropbear

## Background

I'm trying to restore an old DNS/DHCP appliance machine. It's from around 2009 and runs what appears to be a customized Linux 2.6 kernel.

The copy of OpenSSH installed on the appliance appears to have been modified to only allow a proprietary, restricted shell to run. Bash is available, but my usual workarounds of trying to run a command directly with `ssh` or setting up a subsystem that gives me a shell have been unsuccessful - the daemon just closes the connection.

Therefore: I need to come up with a replacement SSHD. This is a very memory-constrained machine, so something simple like [Dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html) would be the way to go.

**Upgrading the machine is not an option at this point**.

## The problem

I have no idea what I need in order to compile Dropbear against Linux 2.6. I've gotten a copy of the Linux sources and a period-accurate Dropbear release, and gotten it to compile as a static binary on X86 (not 64 bit), and messing around with the `make` command's includes to point at those sources, but `file` always tells me that the resulting binary is "For Linux 3.2" anyways.

I've got little C experience beyond following instructions.

What am I missing here, and what is the magic invocation to force `make` to use the Linux 2.6 sources instead of my work system's sources?

Comment: what architecture is your appliance? x86? Have you tried to run your binary on the appliance?

Comment: @arved : X86. Running the generated binary as is causes a segfault.

Comment: do you have gdb on your device? According to the readme a common problem is pty allocation, have you tried to --disable-openpty ?